# applying consistent padding to all GUI widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am building a larger tkinter-based GUI in Python and I am trying to keep the look, especially the spacing, consistent across multiple `ttk.LabelFrame`s, each containing multiple buttons, separators, etc.

At the moment I am using a recursive approach to achieve this goal, something along the lines of:

```
def adjust_children(parent):
    for child in parent.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, ttk.Labelframe):
            child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='senw')
            adjust_children(child)
        elif isinstance(child, ttk.Frame):
            child.grid_configure(padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky='senw')
            adjust_children(child)
        elif isinstance(child, ttk.Separator):
            child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=4)
        else:
            child.grid_configure(padx=2, pady=2)
```

But it seems like changing the ttk style is a more elegant option to achieve the same goal. Yet, while this approach works for some widgets like buttons:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_settings('default', {
    'TButton':{'configure': {'padding': (2, 2)}},
})
```

the above does not seem to work for `TSeparator`. Similarly, I cannot find much information about changing the "internal" padding (`ipadx` and `ipady` above) using styling.

Am I missing something or can I simply not apply padding to a separator using changes to the default ttk style? Is there a better approach than the recursive one shown above?

Comment: A little reading about `ttk.Separator`, _"The only style feature you can configure is background, which specifies the color of the separator bar"_

Comment: Indeed, I looked at pages like https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_separator.htm, yet those also say "Copyright © 2004" and I was hoping to get some more up to date information.

Comment: See [http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_separator.htm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_separator.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to use `Style`, then you could do it this way instead of recursion

```py
def adjust_children (parent) :
    _list=parent.winfo_children()
    for item in _list:
        for widget in list(attrs.keys())[:-1]:
            if isinstance(item,widget):
                item.grid_configure(**attrs[widget])
                break
        else:
            item.grid_configure(**attrs['None'])
        if item.winfo_children():
            _list.extend(item.winfo_children())

attrs={
    ttk.Labelframe: {'padx':10, 'pady':10, 'ipadx':5, 'ipady':5, 'sticky':'senw'},
    ttk.Frame: {'padx':0, 'pady':0, 'ipadx':0, 'ipady':0, 'sticky':'senw'},
    ttk.Separator: {'padx':4, 'pady':4},
    'None': {'padx':2, 'pady':2},
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to extend a list that is being iterated over, but I like the approach of keeping the attributes in its own dictionary similar to the ttk style specification. That seems to be one step closer to specifying the style for all elements in one place.

Based on the lack of responses so far, it appears like there is no alternative tkinter way of achieving this but I will keep this question open a bit longer.

Comment: @japamat Alright and if you don't mind could you please explain why is it not suggested to extend lists that are being iterated?